# AWS Lambda layer for WeasyPrint and jinja2

Tags: python-3.x, aws-lambda, jinja2, aws-lambda-layers, weasyprint

I am trying to create a AWS Lambda layer for WeasyPrint and jinja2. I tried the following steps:

download packages:

```
pip3 install weasyprint
pip3 install jinja2
```

Created a zip file and uploaded it as layers. But it kept throwing module not found error.

To resolve the above error, I followed the steps mentioned here:
https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/lambda-import-module-error-python/

But now it is throwing the errors below:

```
0-0': gobject-2.0-0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory.  Additionally, ctypes.util.find_library() did not manage to locate a library called 'gobject-2.0-0'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.8/imp.py", line 234, in load_module
    return load_source(name, filename, file)
  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.8/imp.py", line 171, in load_source
    module = _load(spec)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 702, in _load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 843, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/var/task/lambda_function.py", line 3, in <module>
    from weasyprint import HTML
```

As mentioned in the installation steps we need to have GTK3 library installed. But how do we get around this problem on aws lambda ? Does anyone have any idea.

thanks

thanks

Comment: You should ask the maintainer of that repo.

Answer (score 2):

`weasyprint` needs some system dependencies which you are not able to install using pip. AWS Lambda is running on `Amazon Linux 2` which doesn't contain some system dependencies such as e.g. `Pango`.
To handle the problem you have to create layer with all needed dependencies. To do this you can use scripts prepared by Kotify what is actually mentioned in weasyprint [official documentation](https://doc.courtbouillon.org/weasyprint/stable/first_steps.html#awsl).

https://github.com/kotify/cloud-print-utils

https://github.com/Kozea/WeasyPrint/issues/1003

Notice that you have to use Python 3.8 runtime.

Answer (score 0):

When installing for lambda layer packaging, you should use `pip install -t <directory path>` option, to install everything to a specific folder. Also, for Python layers, structure should be `python/<your dependencies>` or `python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/<your dependencies>`

You can see it in the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-layers.html)

Comment: I followed the instructions mentioned here:
https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/lambda-import-module-error-python/



but getting the following error now:
0-0': gobject-2.0-0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory.  Additionally, ctypes.util.find_library() did not manage to locate a library called 'gobject-2.0-0'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.8/imp.py", line 234, in load_module